# date structure and linked list printing problem

Tags: c, linked-list, undefined-behavior, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I am trying to creat a linked list in c language,
the code compiles with no error but when I run it , it won't run.

the data structure is a task which contains the label it's number, duration , number of linked tasks which will be put in an array and a pointer to the next task.

here's my code and the test code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tache { //linked listes structure
    char label;
    int num; //task number
    int dure;
    int *inter;
    int n; //nombre d'antécedents
    struct tache * suivant;
}strTache,*pTask;


pTask creerVide(){ //créer une tache vide
    return NULL;
}

pTask firstTask(int d){
    //créer la première tache qui prend la durée en argument
    pTask first = (strTache*)(malloc(sizeof(strTache)));
    first->num = 1;
    first->suivant = NULL;
    first->label = 'A';
    first->dure = d;
    first->n = 0;
    return first;
}

Bool vide(pTask t){return t==NULL;} //check if a liste of tasks is empty this is predefined in a header included in the program

pTask ajouteTask(pTask t, int d){
    pTask new = (strTache*)(malloc(sizeof(strTache)));
    
    if(vide(t)){
        new = firstTask(d);
        t->suivant = new;
        
    }else
    {
        pTask parc = t;
        while(parc->suivant != NULL){parc=parc->suivant;}
            new->num = parc->num+1;
            new->label = parc->label+1;
            new->suivant = parc->suivant;
            parc->suivant = new;
            new->dure=d;
           
    }
    return new;

}

void ajouteInter(pTask p,int numero, int taille, int tab[]){
    int i,j;
    pTask move = p;

    while(move->suivant!=NULL){
        if(move->num != numero){
            move=move->suivant;
        }//fin if
        else 
        {
            move->inter = (int*) malloc(taille*sizeof(int));
            move->n = taille;
        }//fin else
    }//fin while
    for(i=0;i<taille;i++){
        move->inter[i] = tab[i];
    }//fin for
}//fin function


    void affichmat2(pTask p){
    int i = 0;
    pTask parc = p;
    while(parc!= NULL){
        
        printf("la tache %c a %d antécédents : ",parc->label,parc->n);
        for(int j=0;j<parc->n;j++){
            printf("%d ",parc->inter[j]);
            }
        printf("\n");
        parc=parc->suivant;
        i++;
    }
    free(parc);
}

int main()
{
    int b[1] = {1};
    int c[2] = {1,2};

    //pTask t1 = creerVide();

    pTask t1 = firstTask(2);
    pTask t2,t3;
    t2 = ajouteTask(t1,3);
    t3 = ajouteTask(t2,4);
    ajouteInter(t2,2,1,b);
    ajouteInter(t3,3,2,c);
    affichmat2(t1);



    return 0;
}
```

I have made some changes thanks to your advice:

the function ajoutetask which called now addtask:
,,,

```
pTask addTask(pTask t, int d){
    pTask new;
    if(vide(t)){
        new = firstTask(d);
        new->suivant = t;
        
    }else
    {
        new = (strTache*)(malloc(sizeof(strTache)));
        pTask parc = t;
        while(parc->suivant != NULL){parc=parc->suivant;}
            new->num = parc->num+1;
            new->label = parc->label+1;
            new->suivant = parc->suivant;
            parc->suivant = new;
            new->dure=d;
           
    }
    return new;

}
```

,,,

the function ajouteinter which called now add antecedent:

```
void addAntecedent(pTask p,int num, int size, int b[]){

        pTask search = p;
        while(search->num !=num){
            search = search->suivant;
        }
        search->inter = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
        search->n = size;
        for(int i = 0;i<size;i++){
            search->inter[i] = b[i];
        }
    }
```

the changes to the test file :

```
int main (){
      int b[1] = {1};
    int c[2] = {1,2};

    pTask t1 = firstTask(2);
    pTask t2,t3;
    t2 = addTask(t1,3);
    t3 = addTask(t1,4);
    addAntecedent(t1,2,1,b);
    addAntecedent(t1,3,2,c);
    affichmat2(t1);
    return 0;
}
```

the code works properly now

the result :

la tache A a 0 antécédents :
la tache B a 1 antécédents : 1
la tache C a 2 antécédents : 1 2

Comment: When you run this using a debugger, what is the *first* unexpected thing it does?

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger – it's likely you quickly find the error that way.

Comment: General recommendation: Write your code in pure English (including comments) – apart from this language mixture being unaesthetic some day you *will* share your code with non-francophones – and if only here on SO. It helps tremendously not having to *guess* what your functions *should* do instead of *actually* do...

Comment: Prefer `bool` as type, it is standard C – need to include `stdbool.h`, though...

Comment: Can you add the output of the current code and what you expect it to do? Can you elaborate on 'it won't run'?

Comment: 1. Do not hide pointers behind typedefs. It is a very bad practice making code much more error-prone.

Comment: 2. Use objects instead of types in sizeof

Comment: 3. Do not cast the result of malloc. If the code does not compile it means that you are using C++ compiler to compile C code which is not right Example: `strTache *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));`

Comment: Even though coding C you might still want to avoid C++ keywords (`new`) – maybe some day you want to write a header compatible to both C and C++ or port your code from C to C++ – usage of those keywords will bite you then...

Comment: @Scott Hunter I used an online debugger ( this is the first time I use that) and this is what I had : Reading symbols from a.out...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/a.out 

Program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb)

Answer (score 0):

For starters use English words for identifiers.

Your code does not make a sense.

Consider for example the function `ajouteTask`

```
pTask ajouteTask(pTask t, int d){
    pTask new = (strTache*)(malloc(sizeof(strTache)));
    
    if(vide(t)){
        new = firstTask(d);
        t->suivant = new;
        //...
```

If the pointer `t` is equal to `NULL` (that is when the function `vide` returns `1`) then 1) the function invokes undefined behavior due to this statement

```
        t->suivant = new;
```

and 2) it produces a memory leak because at first a memory was allocated and its address was assigned to the pointer new

```
    pTask new = (strTache*)(malloc(sizeof(strTache)));
```

and then the pointer was reassigned

```
        new = firstTask(d);
```

Or within the function `ajouteInter` you have an infinite while loop if `move->num` is equal to `numero`

```
void ajouteInter(pTask p,int numero, int taille, int tab[]){
    int i,j;
    pTask move = p;

    while(move->suivant!=NULL){
        if(move->num != numero){
            move=move->suivant;
        }//fin if
        else 
        {
            move->inter = (int*) malloc(taille*sizeof(int));
            move->n = taille;
        }//fin else
    }//fin while
    //...
```

So what you need is to rework your code and if there will be problems ask a new question.

Comment: would please take a look at my code ?

Answer (score 0):

[Click here](https://uniblogsp.blogspot.com/2022/05/link-list-implementation-in-c-insertion.html)

**https://uniblogsp.blogspot.com/2022/05/link-list-implementation-in-c-insertion.html**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct intnode
{
    int data;
    struct intnode *next;
} intnode;
intnode *create(int n)
{
    intnode *head, *q, *newnode;

    head = (intnode *)malloc(sizeof(intnode));
    scanf("%d", &head->data);
    head->next = NULL;
    q = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        newnode = (intnode *)malloc(sizeof(intnode));
        scanf("%d", &newnode->data);
        newnode->next = NULL;
        q->next = newnode;
        q = newnode;
    }
    return head;
}
void printList(intnode *head)
{
    intnode *temp;
    temp = head;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", head->data);
        head = head->next;
        printf("\n");
    }

    head = temp;
}
void insertList(intnode *head, int i, intnode *t)
{
    intnode *r, *x;
    if (i == 0)
    {
        t->next = head;
        head = t;
        return;
    }
    r = head;
    for (int j = 1; (j < i - 1) && (r != NULL); j++)
    {
        r = r->next;
    }
    if ((r == NULL) && (i > 0))
    {
        return;
    }

    x = r;
    t->next = x->next;
    x->next = t;
    return;
}
void deleteList(intnode *head, int i)
{
    intnode *y, *x;
    y = head;
    if (i == 0)
    {
        head = head->next;
        free(y);
        return;
    }

    x = y->next;
    for (int j = 1; (j < i) && (x != NULL); i++)
    {
        y = x;
        x = x->next;
    }
    if ((x == NULL) && (i > 0))
    {
        return;
    }
    y->next = x->next;
    x->next = NULL;
    free(x);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    int n, l;
    printf("Enter the no of nodes: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the elements of nodes: \n");
    intnode *p = create(n);
    printf("Nodes are: \n");
    printList(p);
    printf("If you want to insert node then press 1 and in case of delete node press 0 : \n");
    int ans;
    scanf("%d", &ans);
    if (ans == 1)
    {
        printf("In what positiomn you want to insert the node ??\n");
        scanf("%d", &l);
        intnode *a;
        a = (intnode *)malloc(sizeof(intnode));
        printf("Enter the node data :\n");
        scanf("%d", &a->data);
        a->next = NULL;
        insertList(p, l, a);
        printf("After insertion the list is : \n");
        printList(p);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("In what positiomn you want to delete the node ??\n");
        scanf("%d", &l);
        deleteList(p, l);
        printf("After deletion the list is : \n");
        printList(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).